# Highstock, multiple series chart, independent xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Following is the chart that I have, 
I want to add xaxis for both the charts depending on their data inputs,

where should I make the change or add xaxis so that I can define the min max limits for the xaxis.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/n24s2fyk/3/

code:

```
$(function () {  
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            navigator:{
                enabled: false
            },
            scrollbar:{
                enabled: false
            },

             rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                 enabled:false
            },


            yAxis: [{
                  min: -1e6,
                max: 1e6,
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    format : ''
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '30%'
            }, {   min: -1e6,
                max: 1e6,
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: -3,
                    format : ''
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0
            }],

            series: [{
                inverted: true,
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'AAPL',

                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4],
                yAxis: 0
            }, {
                inverted: true,
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: [3,6,8,5,2],
                  yAxis: 1

            }]
        });

});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not clear what you are tying to achieve here.  You want each series to have their own x axis and y axis?  Why not have 2 charts?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird well you are right over there, but the charts that I have are related, there are a set of values that always fall between 0-1 for one series, and for other series values always fall between 0-7 hence if both had an axis it would be great to visualize.

Comment: Just add other x-axes the same way as you did for the yAxis. And for setting min and max, again, do it the same way as for yAxis; http://jsfiddle.net/n24s2fyk/5/

Comment: @BarbaraLaird FYI made it work http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/uga37ox0/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
  [http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/uga37ox0/2/][1]

  [http://jsfiddle.net/uga37ox0/1/][1]
```

thanks to the guys from highcharts suppot team

```
 xAxis: [{

            },{
            offset: -245,
            min: 0,
            max: 10
        }],
   series: [{
                inverted: true,
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4],
                yAxis: 0,
                xAxis: 1
            }, {
                inverted: true,
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: [3,6,8,5,2],
                yAxis: 1,
                xAxis:0

            }]
```